# BitBucket show diff indicates the codes are different but actual they are the identical codes

Tags: git, bitbucket

In Bitbucket I have the code xxx.java in develop branch and feature/myBugs branch. They are exactly same, no extra white spaces and no blank lines. Now I use `git diff` tab to show the difference. It shows

```
55     - }
   55  + }
```

55 is the line number.

I don't know why. I use Notepad++ compare plugin to compare them but they are same.

Comment: please have a look of this configuration, how to setup line ending specific to OS.
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings?platform=windows

Comment: The comment has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Please explain in more details: 1. through what screen you see this diff (pull request view ? or diff view ?) 2. how you establish that "xxx.java  is exactly same" in both branches (did you run a git diff command on your machine? copied text from some place ?)

Comment: Is line 55 the last line?
what happens if you add different options for ignoring certain whitespace changes? (see anything starting with --ignore on https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Comment: @LeGEC, I copied the code from those two branches to notepad++. Notepad plus has a compare plugin to compare two files. The comparing can include white spaces and blank lines. I didn't use git diff command. In BitBucket server there is "Diff" tab. The url likes https://bitbucketp.my-company.com/projects/aaa/repos/aaa-api/compare/diff?sourceBranch=refs%2Fheads%2Ffeature/myBugs&targetReold=1234#src/main/java/com/my-company/aaa/model/dto/xxx.java

Comment: @Kim, I don't use git command. I clicked the Diff TAB in the BitBucket web site to compare them. There is a source dropdown and destination dropdown menu, you can compare them. And yes, line 55 is the last line.

Comment: Could you checkout the code before and after the specific commit? It's not enough to copy paste to notepad++ you have to be sure it includes everything, including characters it doesn't necessarily show in the browser. My best guess would be that one version has a newline character at the end while the other don't.

Comment: @Kim, the thing is I already committed the code a few days ago. I just want to revert it. Not sure how because I can't locate the difference.

Comment: oh, in that case I'm asking entirely wrong questions... You have committed it but have you also pushed and merged it? If you haven't it is actually not that hard to fix, you just have to make a commit which undo that particular change. You could run ´git restore --source=<commit-before-change> --patch -- <filepath>´ and only restore the last line of the file. Depending if you are up for rewriting the history so the change isn't part of it you can go further and make the restore as a fixup-commit followed by a rebase.

Comment: @Kim, I have pushed it to the bitbucket server.

Answer (score 0):

On the settings of the pull request you can find an option to hide or show white space changes.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. The codes were already pushed to the Bitbucket server. And I don't find any white space. (I copy and paste the code to Notepad and show all symbols)